# mySQL Insert if id exist else send error to user, what metod can I use?

Tags: php, mysql

I like to change my code up a bit and if the int `$itemID` does not exist the user should trigger `$retval` `die`, if `$itemID` exists the user should proceed with the update of the db.

What method is most suitable?

code:

```
$upd = "UPDATE booking SET userID ='$userID' WHERE itemID ='$itemID'";

$retval = mysql_query($upd, $con);
if(!$retval){
   die('Could not update data: '.mysql_error());
   } 
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
```

Comment: Is there a question here? And you should switch to `mysqli` functions, since `mysql` is deprecated

Comment: I saw that I was quite unclear, text is edited now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check for the number of affected rows, like this:

```
$upd = "UPDATE booking SET userID ='$userID' WHERE itemID ='$itemID'";

$retval = mysql_query($upd, $con);

if(!$retval || 0 === mysql_affected_rows()) {
   die('Could not update data: '.mysql_error());
}

echo "Updated data successfully\n";
```

Also, as stated in the comment, you should be using `mysqli_` or even `PDO` instead of `mysql_`, since the latter is seriously outdated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**mysql_affected_rows()**](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

Example of use from PHP User manual:

> ```
> /* Update records */
> mysql_query("UPDATE mytable SET used=1 WHERE id < 10");
> printf ("Updated records: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
> mysql_query("COMMIT");
> ```

**Please note** that `mysql_*` methods will be deprecated starting php 5.5.0. Alternatively you can use [**PDO prepared statements**](https://www.php.net//manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Yes I will change my code for PDO when I get the function to work correctly

Comment: @user3751216 Perfect ... I provided you with an example of the mysql_affected_rows() which return the number of affected rows :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$upd = "UPDATE booking SET userID ='$userID' WHERE itemID ='$itemID'";

if( isset($itemID) && $retval = mysql_query($upd, $con) ){
    echo "Updated data successfully\n";
}
else {
    die('Could not update data: '.mysql_error());
}
```

(Yes, prudent to update to mysqli_*.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it work

```
if(isset($ItemId))
{
    $upd = "UPDATE booking SET userID ='$userID' WHERE itemID ='$itemID'";
    $retval = mysql_query($upd, $con);
    if(!$retval){
       die('Could not update data: '.mysql_error());
       } 
    echo "Updated data successfully\n";
}
else
{
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check with `empty()`

```
if(!empty($itemID)) {
 $upd = "UPDATE booking SET userID ='$userID' WHERE itemID ='$itemID'";
 $retval = mysql_query($upd, $con);
 if(!$retval){
   die('Could not update data: '.mysql_error());
   } 
 echo "Updated data successfully\n";
}
else {
  echo "Item id not exist\n";    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you formulate the question better? I'm not understanding if you mean to check if the variable exists or a user with that id exists.

If you're checking if the user exists I think you should do a SELECT query to find users with that ID and count the results using mysql_num_rows(), this way you can catch problems before attempting to do an UPDATE query.
Note: like Amir said in his comment, mysql_* will be (or happens to be already) depreciated in PHP, and will be removed in some future version. Try to look into mysqli for an easy upgrade or look into PDO for more advanced functionality.